# Eager loading with condition

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I have question on eager loading in entity framework.

I have two tables ScrappyTemplate and ScarppyTemplateFields, the relationship between the tables is one to many. Note that both the tables have IsActive flag

I want to fetch the data from ScrappyTemplate and ScrappyTemplateFields where IsActive==True, im using the below code to fetch the data via eager loading

```
using (Entities entities = new Entities())
{
var content = entities.ScrappyTemplates.Include(entities.GetTableName<ScrappyTemplateField>   (false)).Where(c => c.ContentSourceId == contentSourceId && c.IsActive == true && c.ScrappyTemplateFields.Any(d=>d.IsActive==true)).ToList<ScrappyTemplate>();
}
```

Im getting the resultset, which is not right!!, i want to get the result set of Child table i.e ScrappyTemplateFields where IsActive=true, but it is returning all rows ir-respective IsActive flag.

Please any one help me, how to place a condition in Child table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Include() does not allow filtering on the related entities. Try this:

```
    using (Entities entities = new Entities())
        {
        var query = from template in entities.ScrappyTemplates
                      where template.ContentSourceId = contentSourceId && template.IsActive = true && template.ScrappyTemplateFields.Any(d=>d.IsActive==true)
                      select new {
                            Template = template,
                            TemplateFields = template.ScrappyTemplateFields.Where(d=>d.IsActive==true)
                      };
      var content = query.ToList().Select(t=>t.Template);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks Khanh,the solution it seems to be working, but is there anyway i can use actual entities instead of using Anonymous types

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way. Let's see if anybody else has a way.

Comment: I finally achieved it, by transforming the Anonymous to Actual type.